# How can I add 'Options' to the gradlew help --task documentation

Tags: android, gradle, documentation, version, task

I have the following setup in my `build.gradle` file:

```
// Task designed to bump version numbers. This should be the first task run     
// after a new release branch is created.                                       
task bumpVersion(description: 'Bumps the version number of the current Android release. Should be used as a standalone task, and should only be the first task called after creating a release branch.', group: 'Management') << {
  Properties props = new Properties();                                          
  File propsFile = new File('gradle.properties');                               
  props.load(propsFile.newDataInputStream());                                   
  def currentVersionCode = props.getProperty("CORE_VERSION_CODE") as int;       
  def currentVersionName = props.getProperty("CORE_VERSION_NAME") as String;    
  def intPortionsOfVersionName = currentVersionName.tokenize('.').toArray();    
  def leastSignificantPortion = intPortionsOfVersionName[intPortionsOfVersionName.length - 1] as int;

  def newVersionCode = currentVersionCode + 1;                                  
  def newVersionName = "";                                                      
  if (!project.hasProperty('newVersion')) {                                     
    leastSignificantPortion = leastSignificantPortion + 1;                      
    intPortionsOfVersionName[intPortionsOfVersionName.length - 1] = leastSignificantPortion;
    newVersionName = intPortionsOfVersionName.collect{ it }.join(".");          
  } else {                                                                      
    newVersionName = project.getProperty('newVersion');                         
  }                                                                             

  props.setProperty("CORE_VERSION_NAME", newVersionName as String);             
  props.setProperty("CORE_VERSION_CODE", newVersionCode as String);             

  props.store(propsFile.newWriter(), null);                                     
}
```

Under the line `newVersionName = project.getProperty('newVersion')` I try to acquire the property called "newVersion", if it exists, and bump the least significant digit if it's not available.

This works fine, but what I want to do is add a way to specify this option in the documentation (i.e. `gradle help --task bumpVersion`). For instance, if I run `gradle help --task help`, it gives me:

```
:help
Detailed task information for help

Path
     :help

Type
     Help (org.gradle.configuration.Help)

Options
     --task     The task, detailed help is requested for.

Description
     Displays a help message
```

Notice how '--task' is under the Options section. I'm wondering how to do this with my own code.

Comment: Hm, so I just realized that I can only specify parameters on the command line via either `-D` or `-P`. This is suboptimal, because I'd like to be able to run `gradle bumpVersion --name <some version name>`. So, it looks like this is perhaps not possible in external tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the `@Option` annotation.

```
@Option(option = "version", description = "Version number to use")
public void setVersion(String version) { ... }
```

**Note:** This is an internal API so it may change.

**Edit:** May have forgotten to mention you will have to implement your task as a [custom task class](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html) to leverage this capability.

Comment: So, do I add the `@Option` annotation to my custom task declaration? I'm not sure how to use it in combination with the custom task class. Could you give a more thorough code example?

Comment: Yes, task a look at the [`DependencyInsightReportTask`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/ccddc438ce09293d84030ebe31668d739c8a228a/subprojects/diagnostics/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/tasks/diagnostics/DependencyInsightReportTask.groovy#L116).